# next git action deploy url

Tags: next.js, deployment, static

In next.js you can use the "public" directory in your root directory to serve static assets. I have my index.html file in this directory because I want my landing page to be purely static.

However, when using next or next start, I cannot access my landing page at http://localhost:3000/. I can only access my landing page at "http://localhost:3000/index.html".

Is there a way to setup next.js, so the top level domain (http://localhost:3000) will serve my landing page?

ex) www.###.com/page (o) <- i want to go url
ex) www.###.com/page.index.html (x) <= now enter url!

plase help me!!